# select a value from a column when the column exists (query portable between postgres version)

Tags: postgresql

I try to refactor a query from a database client that's built dynamically depending on postgres version (pgcli with the pgspecial package). I wonder if it's even possible.
I know the column names upfront, just not the server version.
Currently the query is built in python and has branches that depend on database version - sometimes 4 different queries depending on version. example:

```
    if cur.connection.info.server_version >= 120000:
        relhasoids = "false as relhasoids"
    else:
        relhasoids = "c.relhasoids"
```

or

```
if cur.connection.info.server_version >= 110000:
    """
    CASE
    WHEN p.prokind = 'a' THEN 'agg'
    WHEN p.prokind = 'w' THEN 'window'
    WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
    ELSE 'normal'
    END as "Type"
    """
else:
    """
    CASE
    WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
    WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
    WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
    ELSE 'normal'
    END as "Type" 
    """
```

i wonder if there is a way to move the logic to sql without writing custom functions ??

Comment: There are different columns being used in the case expressions, so it's not the underlying PostgreSQL version that causes the problem - it appears to be caused by differences in the table definition. Is this true? or do both environments share the exact same table definitions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way to do it.

You can have a version-independent view of the database routines in `information_schema.routines`. There are similar version independent views for those other database objects that the SQL standard knows about in the `information_schema`.

Comment: Thanks. I will just use different queries depending on the server version